# react native:now btn is on the top of keyboard

Tags: android-layout, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOYiE.png)

like this,when i touch the TextInput,and the keyboard shows, i want the btn to fix the screen bottom always...but it doesn't work..how can i do?

my code just like this:

`<Container style={{position: 'relative',}}> 
    ...
    <TextInput  placeholder="input something"></TextInput>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', left: 0, bottom: 0,  width: '100%'}}>
    <Separator style={{height:10}}></Separator>
    <Button style={disabledBtn} block disabled>
    <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>ok</Text>
    </Button> 
    <Separator style={{height:5}}></Separator>
    </View>
    </Container>`